# Parsing special character in thymeleaf text template

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using Thymelead Text Temaplate, and want to parse special character like single quote, '&' etc. I am trying like `[# th:text="${'What''s up?'}" /]` but it is throwing following error:

```
ERROR a.c.s.d.o.h.c.SubmissionController - Exception evaluating OGNL expression: "'What''s up?'" (template: "sample-template" - line 63, col 4)
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Exception evaluating OGNL expression: "'What''s up?'" (template: "sample-template" - line 63, col 4)
```

Comment: Check this out :
 https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#unescaped-text

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. This, for example, works for me:

```
<p th:inline="text">
    [# th:text="${'What''s up?'}" /]
</p>
```

Possibly there is something wrong with how Thymeleaf evaluates that your code is text.